# Responsive css loading normal css

Tags: html, css

I am designing a responsive web site. For that web site i am using a div "two". "Two" css is

```
#two { 
overflow:hidden;
min-height: 85px;
margin-left: 22%;
}
```

and responsive css is like fallows

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #two{ 
        //empty field
  }
}
```

when decreasing the browser window, normal css is loading instead of "media screen and (max-width: 400px)"

Comment: It's working fine, please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/zrryezzs/2/

Comment: Your code is working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's behaving as it should be, you have a definition for the ID 2, then if the width is less than 400 pixels you have a second empty definition. So imagine taking out your media clause and you just have this.

```
#two { 
overflow:hidden;
min-height: 85px;
margin-left: 22%;
}
#two{ 
    //empty field
}
```

That's what CSS is active when you have a screen with less than 400 pixels, you could wrap your first definition in an media query to only apply if the screen is larger than 400 pixels, or override each property you set in the first #two block, in the second one inside the media query.